# Smoothness of the Picard group of a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $k=\bar{k}$ and denote its Picard group by $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$, with the usual scheme structure coming from the representability of the relative Picard functor.

It's well known that $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is smooth of dimension $g$ everywhere in the case of characteristic $0$.

For positive characteristic, Igusa and Serre constructed examples of smooth **surfaces** presenting singular Picard groups.

What can be said about smooth curves in positive characteristic? Is the Picard group always smooth?

Comment: Is this really standard terminology? The Picard group is a thing: the group of divisors modulo linear equivalence. It is thus a group. It doesn't make sense to call a group "smooth." I assume you mean Picard scheme? The definition of "the" Picard scheme is a bit more subtle and so one should be careful to define what is exactly meant here.

Comment: You are right on the fact that it's more subtle to define the Picard scheme (it can be done by showing that the relative Picard functor is representable, for instance). I will add this remark to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Picard group splits as the product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the Jacobian variety of $X$, and so each connected component of $\mbox{Pic}(X)$ is (non-canonically) isomorphic to the Jacobian of $X$ which is smooth.

**Edit:** To see that the Picard group splits, consider the exact sequence 
$$0\to\mbox{Pic}^0(X)\to\mbox{Pic}(X)\stackrel{\deg}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to0$$
where $\mbox{Pic}^0(X)=\{\mathcal{O}_X(D):\deg(D)=0\}$. This sequence splits since if $p_0\in X$, we have a section $\mathbb{Z}\to\mbox{Pic}(X)$ where $m\mapsto\mathcal{O}_X(mp_0)$. It is well-known (and most of the time defined this way) that the Jacobian of $X$ is isomorphic to $\mbox{Pic}^0(X)$.

Comment: To prove the Jacobian is smooth, one has to prove that $\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/k}$ is smooth. And here we need the hypothesis that $X$ is a curve because then $H^2(X, O_X)=0$.

Comment: Dear Cantlog: Yes, one criterion for $\mbox{Pic}(X)$ to be smooth is when $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$. Now is smoothness of $\mbox{Pic}^0(X)$ used to prove the existence of the Jacobian variety (as an abelian variety)?

Comment: Dear Robert, the Jacobian *is* Pic$^0$ by definition.

Comment: Dear Cantlog: Yes, and that's why smoothness of $\mbox{Pic}(X)$ is easy, assuming that the Jacobian variety exists (that is, assuming that the functor $\mbox{Pic}^0$ is represented by an abelian variety). Now if you assume that the Jacobian variety exists, it is trivially smooth since it is a group variety. I was just wondering if maybe my answer uses circular logic in the sense that perhaps smoothness of $\mbox{Pic}^0$ was used to prove the existence of the Jacobian (as an abelian variety).

Comment: OK I see. Non, the smoothness of Pic$^0$ is not need to prove the existence (representability) of Pic.